# How to scroll up through integrated terminal with keyboard on visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

I am using Visual studio 2022 and 2019 on windows 10. Is there a way to scroll up and down using the keyboard on the integrated terminal screen opened from the view>terminal tab in visual studio? 
I tried all of the following shortcuts <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up/Down</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up/Down</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Up Arrow/Down</kbd> but doesnt work. I want to scroll up/down in terminal using keyboard without using mouse scroll.

Comment: I have provided feedback for this feature https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Scroll-up-through-integrated-terminal-wi/10397579

Answer (score -1):

in Keyboard shortcuts
search for (Terminal scroll Up(Line)) & (Terminal scroll Down (Line))

edit this shortcut of your choice and this will work.[image]

Comment: thank u for answer but my problem is visual studio not visual studio code. Shortcut you showed is not available in visual studio