# Why aren't VS Code's default keybindings for scrolling an integrated terminal by line working?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

I am using Visual Studio Code, which I like quite a lot except for one thing: It puts output in a middle window between the code and the command line and I can't get this to scroll. It's the area above the command line and below the output, debug, terminal, etc., tabs:
[image]

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72406180/how-to-scroll-up-through-integrated-terminal-with-keyboard-on-visual-studio) points out that there are keyboard shortcuts for scrolling. They show up in my preferences but they have no effect when I try them. When I use the scroll wheel on my mouse it scrolls through command history on the command line. Anyone know how to solve this problem? It's a little astonishing that MS didn't put a scroll bar on that middle window.

Comment: What output window are you referring to? Could you share a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the problem. Other keyboard shortcuts are taking higher priority: `workbench.action.terminal.selectToPreviousCommand` and `workbench.action.terminal.selectToNextCommand` over the `workbench.action.terminal.scrollUp` and `workbench.action.terminal.scrollDown` that you want. Note that you can figure this stuff out on your own by [troubleshooting your keybindings](//github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Keybinding-Issues). Honestly, this seems like weird behaviour and possibly a mistake in VS Code. Not sure.

To get around this, you can either rebind things to non-conflicting keys, or maybe fiddle with when clauses, but the simplest thing would be to just unbind `workbench.action.terminal.selectToPreviousCommand` and `workbench.action.terminal.selectToNextCommand` (and then rebind them to something else if you still want them). You could unbind them by putting the following in your keybindings.json file (which you can open using the `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)):

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+up",
    "command": "-workbench.action.terminal.selectToPreviousCommand",
    "when": "terminalFocus && terminalHasBeenCreated || terminalFocus && terminalProcessSupported"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+down",
    "command": "-workbench.action.terminal.selectToNextCommand",
    "when": "terminalFocus && terminalHasBeenCreated || terminalFocus && terminalProcessSupported"
},
```